# Rails 5.2.1 -> 5.2.2 upgrade on Heroku, deploy crashes with "Could not detect rake tasks"; Solidus 2.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, solidus

after upgrading and bundle install, I get this on deploy

```
Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- polyamorous/activerecord_5.2.2_ruby_2/join_association
```

gemfile OLD

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.2.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'nondestructive_migrations'
gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # gem 'spring'
  # gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'solidus', '2.7.0'

gem 'solidus_auth_devise'
gem 'solidus_print_invoice' , github: 'solidusio-contrib/solidus_print_invoice'
gem 'solidus_gateway'
```

gemfile NEW (causes crash)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.2.5'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

gem 'nondestructive_migrations'
gem 'acts_as_paranoid', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
gem 'activerecord-session_store'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # gem 'spring'
  # gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'solidus', '2.7.0'

gem 'solidus_auth_devise'
gem 'solidus_print_invoice' , github: 'solidusio-contrib/solidus_print_invoice'
gem 'solidus_gateway'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed by bumping Solidus `2.7.0` to Solidus `2.7.1`